# Difficulty executing this code which prints out the time

Tags: java

```
int hour, minute, second;
String amOrPm = "AM", "PM";
```

I keep getting an error when I execute this code, can someone help me fix it?

Comment: You only have one error here: you are attempting to assign two values to one `String`.

Comment: @ElliottFrisch How can I fix this error?

Comment: Give the `String` one value; what is this intended to do? Because it does not print the time.

Answer (score 1):

Here:

```
String amOrPm = "AM", "PM";
```

That line declares *one* variable, followed by **two** values, separated by a comma. You can't have a string variable holding two independent strings "AM" and "PM"!

You could declare two variables am and pm and then write other code that decides which of the two should be used!

Answer (score 1):

The code you gave doesn't really do much.

in the first line

`int hour, minute, second;`

you are creating variables that hold numbers. Think of them as boxes that you can put whatever you want in (but only numbers, specifically whole numbers for `int`)

The first line is equivalent to writing

```
int hour;
int minute;
int second;
```

which creates 3 "boxes" with labels `hour` `minute` and `second`

The second line actually has an error, a variable only holds one value but you try to give it 2.

I think what you wanted to have was this

```
String AM = "AM";
String PM = "PM";
```

however, depending on what you're doing, they may not be necessary.

Some code that prints AM or PM depending on the time (or more precisely, the value of `hour` that *you* define and set) might look like this:

```
if (hour < 12) {
    System.out.println("AM");
} else {
    System.out.println("PM");
}
```

This code says "if the box that is remembering what hour it is, is storing a value less than 12, it must be AM so print that. otherwise, its PM"

if you wanted to write some code that changed a `String` variable based on the time, it might look like this:

```
int hour = 13;
String amOrPm;

if (hour < 12) {
    amOrPm = "AM";        
} else {
    amOrPm = "PM";
}
```

This code would set the variable `amOrPm` to be "PM", because I chose the hour to be `13`.

Comment: That is a nice answer giving a lot of helpful insights!